# Pass json_value into stored procedure

Tags: json, sql-server

I am trying to parse JSON and pass the key-value pairs into a stored procedure.

```
declare @json nvarchar(max) = '{"bin":1,"type":"A"}',
@id int = 1234

exec someStoreProcedure select 
json_value(@json, '$.bin'), 
json_value(@json, '$.type'),
@id
```

How can I pass in `json_values` to a stored procedure?

Comment: You would have to assign the to variables first; you cannot pass expressions to a Stored Procedure parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-- Inputs

declare @json nvarchar(max) = '{"bin":1,"type":"A"}',
@id int = 1234

-- Map json to variables

declare @bin int = json_value(@json, '$.bin')
declare @type nvarchar(10) = json_value(@json, '$.type')

-- Pass variables into procedure

exec someStoreProcedure select 
@bin, 
@type,
@id
```