# Store D2C messages in Azure SQL database

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics, cloudrail

I am trying to store sensor readings received from Cloudrail.Box as a JSON payload into Azure SQL database.
The edge function I'm currently using outputs the message(shown below) in batches based on the set frequency.
{
"Temp_V_Raw": 0.789,
"Pressure_V_Raw": 0.006,
"Temp_C": 23.67,
"Pressure_Bar": 1.8450718792014,
"Timestamp": 1617990070392,
"Date": "Fri Apr 09 2021 19:41:10 GMT+0200 (CEST)"
}

HOw do I store this in a tabular format in Azure SQL database?

Comment: I would suggest you create a stored procedure to deal with the json data, then you pass the JSON data into the Azure SQL database by a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you create a stored procedure to deal with the json data, then you pass the JSON data into the Azure SQL database by a stored procedure.

Ref the stored procedure example:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SystemRecord(
    RecordedDateTime        datetime2(0) NOT NULL,
    RecordedDateTimeLocal   datetime2(0) NOT NULL,
    CpuPctProcessorTime     smallint     NOT NULL,
    MemAvailGbytes          smallint     NOT NULL
)

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertSystemRecordData
 
@json NVARCHAR(max)

AS
BEGIN
 
INSERT INTO dbo.SystemRecord (
  [RecordedDateTime]
, [RecordedDateTimeLocal]
, [CpuPctProcessorTime]
, [MemAvailGbytes])
 
    SELECT
        RecordedDateTime
       ,RecordedDateTimeLocal
       ,CpuPctProcessorTime
       ,MemAvailGbytes
    FROM OPENJSON(@json)
    WITH (
      RecordedDateTime      DATETIME2(0) '$.dateTime'
    , RecordedDateTimeLocal DATETIME2(0) '$.dateTimeLocal'
    , CpuPctProcessorTime   SMALLINT     '$.cpuPctProcessorTime'
    , MemAvailGbytes        SMALLINT     '$.memAvailGbytes'
    ) AS jsonValues
 
END

EXEC dbo.InsertSystemRecordData @json ='{"dateTime":"2018-03-19T15:15:40.222Z","dateTimeLocal":"2018-03-19T11:15:40.222Z","cpuPctProcessorTime":"0","memAvailGbytes":"28"}'
```

You could ref these links:

1. [Pass json_value into stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64974449/pass-json-value-into-stored-procedure)
2. [How to Insert JSON Data into SQL Server Database](https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/how-to-insert-json-data-into-sql-server-database/)

HTH.